# Kubernetes worker nodes not automatically being assigned podCidr on kubeadm join

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, flannel

I have a multi-master Kubernetes cluster set up, with one worker node. I set up the cluster with kubeadm. On `kubeadm init`, I passed the `-pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` (using Flannel as the network overlay).

When using `kubeadm join` on the first worker node, everything worked properly. For some reason when trying to add more workers, none of the nodes are automatically assigned a podCidr.

I used [this](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md) document to manually patch each worker node, using the 
`kubectl patch node <NODE_NAME> -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"<SUBNET>"}}'` command and things work fine.

But this is not ideal, I am wondering how I can fix my setup so that just adding the `kubeadm join` command will automatically assign the podCidr.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

```
I1003 23:08:55.920623       1 main.go:475] Determining IP address of default interface

I1003 23:08:55.920896       1 main.go:488] Using interface with name eth0 and address 

I1003 23:08:55.920915       1 main.go:505] Defaulting external address to interface address ()

I1003 23:08:55.941287       1 kube.go:131] Waiting 10m0s for node controller to sync

I1003 23:08:55.942785       1 kube.go:294] Starting kube subnet manager

I1003 23:08:56.943187       1 kube.go:138] Node controller sync successful

I1003 23:08:56.943212       1 main.go:235] Created subnet manager:
```

Kubernetes Subnet Manager - kubernetes-worker-06

```
I1003 23:08:56.943219       1 main.go:238] Installing signal handlers

I1003 23:08:56.943273       1 main.go:353] Found network config - Backend type: vxlan

I1003 23:08:56.943319       1 vxlan.go:120] VXLAN config: VNI=1 Port=0 GBP=false DirectRouting=false

E1003 23:08:56.943497       1 main.go:280] Error registering network: failed to acquire lease: node "kube-worker-02" pod cidr not assigned

I1003 23:08:56.943513       1 main.go:333] Stopping shutdownHandler...
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in your flannel pods that don't get the podCIDR assigned to them?

Comment: Hi, yes. The kube-flannel-ds pod keeps starting, failing, and restarting. Adding the log output as an edit to my post.

Comment: provide your k8s component versions and share information on how you enabled flannel. I have recreated your case(v1.12.0). 1) kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16; 2)kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml; 3)joined 4 nodes - all of them are up and running without issues and all have proper  podCIDR

Comment: I've done pretty much the same as you described, except my Kubernetes version is v1.11.2. I passed the pod-network-cidr in kubeadm init, applied the same yaml, and the first worker node I brought up worked fine, but subsequent nodes present the issue I described.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve my issue. In my multi-master setup, on *one* of my master nodes, the `kube-controller-manager.yaml` (in /etc/kubernetes/manifest) file was missing the two following fields:

- `--allocate-node-cidrs=true`
- `--cluster-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`

Once adding these fields to the yaml, I reset the `kubelet` service and everything was working great when trying to add a new worker node.

This was a mistake on my part, because when initializing one of my master nodes with `kubeadm init`, I must of forgot to pass the `--pod-network-cidr`. Oops.

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a couple of worker nodes like I did rather than kubeadm revert and then passing in the kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16  you can do the following on each node and issue should disappear:

kubectl patch node node2-worker -p '{"spec":{"podCIDR":"10.244.0.0/16"}}'

where node2-worker is your node name and not the one shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `kubernetes v1.16` with `docker-ce v17.05`. The thing is, I only have one master node, which is `init`ed with `--pod-network-cidr` option.

The flannel pod on another worker node failed to syncing, according to kubelet log under `/var/log/message`. Checking this pod (with `docker logs <container-id>`), it turned out that `node <NODE_NAME> pod cidr not assigned`.

I fixed it by manually set the podCidr to the worker node, according to [this doc](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md)

Although I've not yet figured out why this manually set-up is required, because as the the doc pointed out:

> If kubeadm is being used then pass --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 to kubeadm init which will ensure that all nodes are automatically assigned a podCIDR.